# How to (partially) order selection so that rows are ordered for each specific user id?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Typically using `ORDER BY` on a large selection runs on a single node which is not preferable. To remedy this I am fine with having my result ordered so that for a specific user's timestamps are in ascending order but not necessarily globally.

How can one achieve this?

E.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY timestamp OVER (PARTITION BY user_id)
```

Which should result in result being ordered by timestamp when considering one user at a time.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample .. the expected  result .. and also the code you are using

Comment: Your attempted solution is not going to fix anything in terms of performance.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`ORDER BY user, timestamp`

this will sort users first and all duplicate `user` will be sorted by `timestamp`.

UPDATE:
Order can also be changed for every column

`ORDER BY user DESC, timestamp ASC`

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very specific, so it's hard to give a specific answer. You can use a query of this form:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  user_id,
  ARRAY_AGG(
    STRUCT(user_timestamp, user_event)
    ORDER BY user_timestamp
  ) AS user_attributes
FROM UserTable
GROUP BY user_id
```

This builds an array with user attributes for each user ID, ordered by a user timestamp.